# Ajax search logic needs improvement

Tags: php, sql, ajax

I'm getting slow (2 second) response times from my ajax search querying. I believe it has to do with my logic. Here is a description of my logic:

- The user types in a permutation of words.
- In my code, I split the string into separate words.
- For each word, I run a query that selects the data which contains the word. I am using LIKE statements, because I am trying to find data which contains the word.
- Finally, I perform an `array_intersect` against the data sets, leaving me with only the results which contain all of the words in the querying.
- I immediately send the json response.

I believe that I should either be doing a `union` against the words, or maybe performing one select statement that contains `AND` statements against all of the words.

```
    foreach($searchParts as $part){
        $sql="SELECT contacts.id AS contactid
        FROM contacts   
        WHERE contacts.addressbook_id =$addressBookId AND";
        $sql.="(contacts.firstname LIKE '%".$part."%' OR ";
        $sql.="contacts.middlename LIKE '%".$part."%' OR ";
        $sql.="contacts.lastname LIKE '%".$part."%' OR ";
        $sql.="contacts.primary_emailaddress LIKE '%".$part."%' OR ";
        $sql.="contacts.alternate_emailaddress LIKE '%".$part."%' OR ";
        //$sql.="contacts.gender LIKE '%".$part."%' OR ";
        $sql.="contacts.personal_address_line1 LIKE '%".$part."%' OR ";
        $sql.="contacts.personal_address_line2 LIKE '%".$part."%' OR ";
        $sql.="contacts.personal_address_city LIKE '%".$part."%' OR ";
        $sql.="contacts.personal_address_zipcode LIKE '%".$part."%' OR ";
        $sql.="contacts.company_name LIKE '%".$part."%' OR ";
        $sql.="contacts.company_position LIKE '%".$part."%' OR ";
        $sql.="contacts.company_address_line1 LIKE '%".$part."%' OR ";
        $sql.="contacts.company_address_line2 LIKE '%".$part."%' OR ";
        $sql.="contacts.company_address_city LIKE '%".$part."%' OR ";
        $sql.="contacts.company_address_zipcode LIKE '%".$part."%' OR ";
        $sql.="contacts.home_phonenumber LIKE '%".$part."%' OR ";
        $sql.="contacts.company_phonenumber LIKE '%".$part."%' OR ";
        $sql.="contacts.cell_phonenumber LIKE '%".$part."%' OR ";
        $sql.="contacts.birthday_month LIKE '%".$part."%' OR ";
        $sql.="contacts.birthday_day LIKE '%".$part."%' OR ";
        $sql.="contacts.birthday_year LIKE '%".$part."%' OR ";
        $sql.="contacts.facebook_username LIKE '%".$part."%' OR ";
        $sql.="contacts.twitter_username LIKE '%".$part."%' OR ";
        $sql.="contacts.googleplus_username LIKE '%".$part."%' OR ";
        $sql.="contacts.linkedin_username LIKE '%".$part."%' OR ";
        $sql.="contacts.personal_website_url LIKE '%".$part."%')";
        $sql.=" ORDER BY contacts.date_created DESC";
        $result=mysql_query($sql,$dbh);
        if($result && mysql_num_rows($result)){
            while(($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))!==false){
                $tmpArr[$part][]=$row['contactid'];
            }
        }
    }
    foreach($tmpArr as $part => $data){
        $tmpArr[$part] = array_unique($tmpArr[$part]);
    }
    if(count($tmpArr)>1){
        $tmpArr = array_values(call_user_func_array("array_intersect", $tmpArr));
    } else {
        $tmpArr = $tmpArr[$searchParts[0]];
    }
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Can't you do a `WHERE IN()` in your query instead of firing a query for each word? In ayway, it's hard to tell if that is really the bottleneck though. You could do some benchmarking to see what part takes the longest.

Comment: I also think it would be the "separation of words and separate-queries for each word-part" that take the longest time, but that is just a qualified guess. If you want more help, please supply your actual code so we can figure out what's going on.

Comment: @w00 I updated my question. I am using LIKE statements. How would I perform a where in clause using like statements?

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld I agree. I will post my code immediately.

Comment: Ok, looking at your code now. Now I'm almost sure the sql-execution time is taking the longest (You could of course try one single sql-statement and see how long it takes. Multiply that with number of words). My tips is to look into fulltext-searching. Somewhere to start: http://devzone.zend.com/26/using-mysql-full-text-searching/

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld I think using FULLTEXT and matches might be the solution. My question though. In the article, they use the following to create an index: ALTER TABLE articles ADD FULLTEXT(body, title); For my solution, would I add all the fields I am querying in the ADD statement for the fulltext index creation sql?

Comment: @jkushner, yeah you've got it right.

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld How do I handle integers in the fulltext? If I cannot, do I do a subsequent query against integers?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34311/discussion-between-bestprogrammerintheworld-and-jkushner)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is to use fulltext-search for columns that contains characters (like varchars), and REGEXP-functionality for INT-values.

You're executing an sql-statement for each word, you should try to change this to execute one single statement for all words
and get the result directly. This will speed up your query and proabably make it easier to read your code.

You should also consider using PDO or mysqli instead of mysql_* functions because mysql_* functions are deprecated.

if you want more help, please tell :-)

Comment: the loading times for sending a request using ajax search against 200 contacts using just the letter 'a' is returning a JSON response in 185 ms on my computer with 25 total results. i consider this a major improvement. thanks -)

Comment: Glad to help. If you want to - update your question or make an answer with your new code. I think other will gain from it :-)